# Entity Framework, ArgumentNullException

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have database with simple structure:

```
markimaster(id, name), modelemaster(id, marka_id), typymaster(id, model_id)
```

I defined relationships between tables and fetch data with this code:

```
ObjectQuery<markimaster> markiQuery = context.markimaster.Include("modelemaster.typymaster");

bindingSourceMarki.DataSource = markiQuery;
```

Last line throws ArgumentNullException with ParamName:entity.
When I change my code to this:

```
ObjectQuery<markimaster> markiQuery = context.markimaster.Include("modelemaster");

bindingSourceMarki.DataSource = markiQuery;
```

it work's (means doesn't throw exception), so i thought maybe there is row in typymaster that didn't have coresponding row in modelemaster, but checking database shows nothing.

Since I'm new to EntityFramework I have no idea what's wrong, so came here looking for advise ;)

[UPDATE]

I ran other query on my database:

select * from modelemaster where model_id not in (select model_id from typymaster)

which returns 2000 rows. So there are models that has no types.

[UPDATE]

This is fragment of my .edmx file

```
EntitySet Name="markimaster" EntityType="MMT_Master.store.markimaster"  store:Type="Tables" Schema="public" 
EntitySet Name="modelemaster" EntityType="MMT_Master.store.modelemaster" store:Type="Tables" Schema="public"
EntitySet Name="typymaster" EntityType="MMT_Master.store.typymaster" store:Type="Tables" Schema="public"
```

so it seems like names used in path passed to Include are correct

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you change the first piece of code with

```
bindingSourceMarki.DataSource = markiQuery.Execute(MergeOption.AppendOnly);
```

? According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738469.aspx):

> To bind objects to a Windows Form control, set the DataSource property of the control to the EntityCollection *or to the ObjectResult that is returned when the Execute method is called on an ObjectQuery object*.

Comment: Thank's for reply. it's the same, but I've updated new info. Do you think this might be a problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be associated with the wrong EntitySet name. 
Please check that you have passed the correct path to Include (maybe pluralization or case sensitivity issue).

Comment: i added fragment of .edmx file to the question. it seems like names are correct